# Hasura request headers in mutation

Tags: hasura

Is there any way to include request header in mutation variable?

Say, I have CF-Connecting-IP: 128.0.0.1 in my request header and i need to insert in in mutation like

```
mutation MyQuery {
  insert_signatures(objects: 
    {ip: CF-Connecting-IP}) {
   returning {
     ip
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is currently not possible: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/2951#issuecomment-605525605. Hopefully that will change.